# I have to run all the tests in a suite with one login data from excel file then logout and pick other login data and run the same tests

Tags: java, selenium, testng, data-driven-tests

I'm using Java selenium in TestNg and Apache POI for excel read. The DataProvider method is only for tests level so the login test repeats 2 times and then its moving to next tc. what can i do to repeat whole suite for all login data from excel.

Also i'm using Page Object Model, so is there any parameter i have to pass on the page object code?

```
 DataProvider:
    public class DataProviders {
        
    
        @DataProvider(name = "loginData")
    
        public Object[][] getLogindata() throws IOException {
    
            Object[][] excelData = ExcelRead.getLoginData();
    
            return excelData;
    
        }
    
    }

    TestCase:
    
    public class LoginScript extends TestBaseUpdate {
        Login loginPage_obj = new Login();
        
            
        
        @Test(priority = 1 , dataProvider = "loginData",dataProviderClass = DataProviders.class ) 
        
        public void TestCase_5_login(String[] Data) throws Exception {
            
            String testcasename = new Object() {}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName();
            
            try {
                
                new Login().VerifyValidUserLogin(Data[0],Data[1]);
            
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
    
            }
        }
    Excel read:
    public static Object[][] getLoginData() throws IOException {
        
        
        String fileLocation = ".\\TestData\\TestDataNav.xlsx";
        
        XSSFWorkbook wbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileLocation);
        
        XSSFSheet sheet =   wbook.getSheetAt(0);
        
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum(); 
    
    System.out.println(lastRowNum);
    
    int lastCellNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    
    System.out.println(lastCellNum);
    
    Object[][] data = new String[lastRowNum][lastCellNum];
        
        for (int i = 1; i <=lastRowNum; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < lastCellNum ; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                
                DataFormatter dft = new DataFormatter();
                
                String value = dft.formatCellValue(cell);
                
                //String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                
                System.out.println(value);
                
                data[i-1][j] = value;
            } 
        }
        
        wbook.close();
        return data;

    }
```

Comment: do you want to test the log in with multiple data or do you want to do the scenarios with multiple logins please provide some code

Comment: I have multiple set of username and password so i have run all the tests for that much of time

Answer (score 0):

Create a method where you read all the test from Execl and assign it to List. Similarly read all the testdata for each test and assign it to another list.
Now create a method at which you use data provider with return type as object[][].
In this method create a for loop to iterate around the list of testcases. and inside this for loop create another for loop to iterate around the list of testdata for each testcase and add each test data for each testcase to the object[][] data.

now pass this object[][] data to the method where you use @Test to begin the execution of each testcase.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for the whole process. So it could be more understandable for me.

Comment: it would be the whole framework which would be difficult to cover here. But seeing above your code , you are running test on login. But i just part of your whole test not whole test. 1st of all are you using BDD, or Data Driven or key word driven framework.   Say you want to login goto home page, go to abc page and log out. in such case, write a method for login, navigate to home page another method, navigate to abc page another method and logout and other method. now create a excel sheet /xml in case u want to go for Data driven or keyword driven.

Comment: and assign each testcase an id and assign data to it in excel. create a method for with name same as your testcase id and call all those login,hoepage etc method in that based on your step. you need to repeat the same for  all other testcases. now iterate through ur excel and when tc id matches call the corresponding tc case method. u need to pass the tc id and its data to dataprovider.

Comment: if you are using BDD then its quite easy , get the scenarios via the Data provider. in each scenario for each statement u need to write the step definition